# Doctrine2 findBy ... where

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am using `Doctrine2 (Symfony2)`, in my controller I used one repository for one table (MySQL) and it does work. I want to add one repository more and find a record where one field is equal to a field from first (previous) table. 
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where 'table2.columnX' = 'table1.columnX';


$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$employee = $em->getRepository('SomethingBundle:Employee')->find($id); [table1 -- it works!]
```

how here:

```
$repository2 = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('NenadStoreBundle:Requirements');


$requirements = $repository2->findById *----where columnX = employeecolumnx
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it this way. Use query builder http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

With `findBy(array $criteria)` , if you already know the "employeecolumnx" value, you can do what you need.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$employee = $em->getRepository('SomethingBundle:Employee')->find($id);
$requirements = $em->getRepository('NenadStoreBundle:Requirements')->findBy(
    array(
        'RequirementColumnX' => $employee->getEmployeeColumnX()
    )
);
```

Change `$employee->getEmployeeColumnX()` with the real method name you need to use.